# In tkinter, how do I remove labels from one function when I run a search and the results are displayed as new labels?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, label, overlap

I have a function that displays data from a table when my window first pops up:

```
def query():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('movie_catalog.db')
    # Create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

# Query the database
    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM movies ORDER BY title ASC")
    records = c.fetchall()

    for index, x in enumerate(records):
        num = 0
        for y in x:
            query_label = Label(root, text=y)
            query_label.grid(row=index + 2, column=num, pady=2)
            num += 1

    # Commit our changes
    conn.commit()

    # Close database connection
    conn.close()
```

I have the loop running to have each row of data in my table display itself in a new row in my window. But I want those to disappear when I run the following search function:

```
def search_movies():
    # Create a database or connect to one
    conn = sqlite3.connect('movie_catalog.db')
    # Create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    selected = drop.get()
    if selected == "Search by":
        test = Label(root, text="Please make a selection")
        test.grid(row=0, column=6)
    if selected == "Title":
        sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title=?"
    if selected == "Year":
        sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year=?"
    if selected == "Genre":
        sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE genre=?"
    if selected == "Director":
        sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE director=?"
    if selected == "Cast":
        sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE cast=?"
    if selected == "Tags":
        sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE tags=?"

    searched = search_box.get()
    caps = searched.title()
    t = (caps, )
    result = c.execute(sql, t)
    result = c.fetchall()
    if result:
        for index, x in enumerate(result):
            num = 0
            for y in x:
                searched_label = Label(root, text=y)
                searched_label.grid(row=index + 2, column=num, pady=2)
                num += 1

    if not result:
        no_result = Label(root, text="Movie not found")
        no_result.grid(row=2, column=2)

    # Commit our changes
    conn.commit()

    # Close database connection
    conn.close()
```

This search function is essentially set up to display the results in the same format as the first function, but I need the original labels to disappear, because my search results are overlapping them. Is there a way to destroy() the display from the first function?

Comment: What do you want to destroy?

Comment: I want to destroy the label that were created from the first function (query). That function displays the data from my table, which right now is 4 rows of data, or labels. In the search function, I want those 4 labels to be destroyed, and replaced by the new label, or 'search results'.

Comment: Create a new window? and `destroy()` the other window?

Comment: I've tried using both **query_label. destroy()** and **query_label.forget()**, with **query_label** set as global. Neither one works? Id rather keep them in the same window.

Comment: I mean to use `root.destroy()`

Comment: I'd like to keep this in the same window if I can. If used the **.destroy()** method in the past on labels, I'm not sure why it isn't working for this one.

Comment: It isnt working ?